# Can we increase an iterator multiple positions without the 'advance' function?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, listiterator

I know we can use `advance()` function to increment the iterator. We also use `iterator++` to increase the iterator by one position.  Why we cannot use `it+=2`?

```
int main()
{
    list<int> l1{1, 2, 3, 5, 6};
    list<int> l2{2, 6, 8};
    auto it = l1.begin();
    advance(it, 2);         //works
    it++;                   //works
    // it+=2;                  //not work
    l2.splice(l2.begin(), l1, it);

    for(int a: l2) cout<<a<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can run the above code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ry8MeNeh7).

Comment: List has a bidirectional iterator, not a random access iterator. `advance` uses compile time machinery to optimize advance operation for different kinds of iterators.

Comment: So your question is: _"why wasn't `operator+=()` specified as syntactic sugar around `std::advance()`?"_ or is it really _"why can't I use `operator+=()` here?"_

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`operator +=` is only supported by [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator); note that it's supposed to have constant complexity.

The iterator of [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which doesn't support `operator +=`. (The iterator of `std::vector` and `std::array` is RandomAccessIterator.)

Note that both of them could be used with [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), when used for RandomAccessIterator complexity is constant; when used for other InputIterators (including BidirectionalIterator) complexity is linear. That means using `std::advance` is a good idea because it's more general and could take advantage of the benefit of RandomAccessIterator automatically.

Comment: Whether `std::advance` is a good idea depends on the complexity guarantee you wish for your algorithm. Using `+=` ensures that should somebody accidentally call your algorithm with a non-RandomAccessIterator, they will get a compile-time error instead of a painfully slow algorithm. For example, if `std::sort` used `std::advance`, you could call it on `std::list`...

Comment: If you want to enforce a compile time complexity based on an IteratorCategory, do it with a static_assert, not with some syntax that does not work with a too weak iterator...

Comment: Why 'operator ++' is still valid here?

Comment: @LushaLi It's supported by all the [InputIterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), including BidirectionalIterator and RandomAccessIterator. And see [the comment from PeteBecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002491/can-we-increase-an-iterator-multiple-positions-without-the-advance-function/53002581#comment92921777_53002792), it might help you to understand why iterators are designed in this way.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot use `+= 2` with this iterator because in general case incrementing `std::list<>` iterator by an arbitrary value is a relatively *inefficient* operation. `+=` is not defined for your iterator type specifically to prevent you from carelessly/unknowingly using this inefficient operation in your code. Instead, if you really want to do that you are supposed to use `std::advance`, which is a "red flag" function that is intended to highlight the fact that you are likely doing something inefficient. `std::advance` is mostly intended for code sketching or for *unlikely-to-get-executed* fallback code. You are not supposed to gratuitously use `std::advance` in production code. If you suddenly find yourself relying on `std::advance`, it means that you probably need to redesign your data structures. Basically, `std::advance` is like a cast - avoid it unless you have a very very very good reason to use it.

Alternatively, you can use `std::next`

```
it = std::next(it, 2);
```

This function is much easier to use than `std::advance`. By default this function is designed to advance the iterator by 1 step forward, but you can specify the second parameter to move it farther. Again, when the value of second parameter is non-constant and potentially large, it should be considered a "red flag" function. A constant value of 2 is definitely within acceptable bounds.

Comment: The reason that `+=` is associated with a constant time operation, is possibly because *pointers* are normally the first iterator type that one is introduced to and naturally supports pointer arithmetic from its c legacy - just neat to understand that this interface design was more or less forced onto c++ by existing culture.

Comment: @WorldSEnder -- `+=` is associated with constant time operation because that's the way the STL (Standard Template Library) was designed: iterator operations are constant-time. Period. Things like `std::advance` and `std::next` are conveniences that were added by revisionists who didn't understand the elegance of the original formulation. <g> But seriously: those are conveniences, and they're named functions and not operators to help make it clear that they can be expensive.